# How to call a variable of a function using concatenation (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, function, concatenation

I need to acess a variable inside this function using concatenation, following this example:

```
public function movePlates():void
{
    var plate1:Plate;
    var plate2:Plate;
    var cont:uint = 0;

    for (var i:uint = 0; i < LAYER_PLATES.numChildren; i++)
    {
        var tempPlate:Plate = LAYER_PLATES.getChildAt(i) as Plate;

        if (tempPlate.selected)
        {
            cont ++;

            this["plate" + cont] = LAYER_PLATES.getChildAt(i) as Plate;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
public function testFunction():void
{
    var test1:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var test2:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var tempNumber:Number;
    this.addChild(test1);
    test1.x = 100;
    this.addChild(test2);
    test2.x = 200;

    for (var i:uint = 1; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        tempNumber += this["test" + i].x;
    }

    trace("tempNumber: " + tempNumber);
}
```

If i run the code like this, the line this["test" + i] returns a variable of the class. I need the local variable, the variable of the function.

Comment: So, what's wrong? `var obj1:Object = new Object();
var obj2:Object = new Object();

trace (obj1 == obj2);
this ["obj" + 1] = obj2;
trace (obj1 == obj2);`
It works (`false true` in output)

Comment: this line:

this["plate" + cont] = LAYER_PLATES.getChildAt(i) as Plate;

try to acess a object propriety, and returns a can't found error.

Comment: I cannot test your code because of luck enviromnent. Trace `cont`, trace `this["plate" + cont]`, trace `LAYER_PLATES.getChildAt(i) as Plate` and examine log.

Comment: You should instead use an Array, at least as good practice.

Comment: Please, look at the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get the local variable with [] notation. your case has  many solutions. You can use dictionary, or getChildAt() function:

```
function testFunction():void
{
    var dict = new Dictionary(true);
    var test1:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var test2:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var tempNumber:Number = 0;

    addChild(test1);
    dict[test1] = test1.x = 100;

    addChild(test2);
    dict[test2] = test2.x = 200;

    for (var s:* in dict)
    {
        tempNumber += s.x;
        //or tempNumber += dict[s];
    }

    trace("tempNumber: " + tempNumber);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop on first step access `plate0` this will cause not found error, if `plate0` is not explicitly defined as class member variable or if class is not defined as dynamic. Same thing will happen for `plate3, plate4, plate5...` in case `LAYER_PLATES.numChildren` is more than 3.

EDIT:

Thanks to @Smolniy he corrected my answer `plate0` is never accessed because `cont` is incremented before first access. So as he mentioned problem should be on `plate3`

Comment: `cont++` before first access. He's accessing `plate1` at first loop, but on `plate3` there's must be error...